# Web Browser "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to code a program that would synchronize the scrolling of two PDFs between two computers. I have no experience in C# programming but I have fooled around with Visual C++ alot. Anyway, my problem is that whenever I run my still very basic code I get the following error message:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." with a break or continue option.

Here's my code for now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DocSync
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\someDocument.pdf");

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            label1.Text= webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any response. Also, I would appreciate any suggestions to how to proceed with what I want to achieve.

Comment: When you navigate to a PDF file using the WebBrowserControl, webBrowser1.Document is null and that is causing the exception.  As an example, change the filename to "www.google.com" and your code will not throw an exception.

Comment: oh.. Then how do you suggest I go around this. I tried using acrobats library but after endless hours of trying I just gave up on it.